# Proc SQL SAS Export to CSV throwing access error

Tags: sas, export

I have a set of code that keeps throwing an error and can't figure out why;

ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access 
       /sas/config9_4/compute/Lev2/SASApp/\VA019\F01B\Everyone\B_ADHOC\MWDATA\Student_D_Repor
       t_20190416.csv.

```
ERROR: Insufficient authorization to access 
       /sas/config9_4/compute/Lev2/SASApp/\\VA019\F01B\Everyone\.......

PROC EXPORT OUTFILE="\\VA019\F01B\Everyone\B_ADHOC\MWDATA\Student_D_Report_&mToday..csv" 
            DATA= Student_D_Report
            DBMS=CSV   REPLACE;
            run;
```

I was exporting to xlsb in excel format and it was working fine. Code below

```
PROC EXPORT OUTFILE="\\\VA019\F01B\Everyone\B_ADHOC\MWDATA\Student_D_Report_&mToday..xlsb" 

            DATA= Student_D_Report
            DBMS=   EXCELCS   REPLACE;
            SHEET='DEBIT';
           run;
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

It appears you had been running SAS EG connected to localhost and writing to Windows network share `\\VA019`.  The error appears as if you are now connected to a SAS server running on Unix and trying to write to the same Windows network share, and the Unix box login is trying to use the old Windows network share.

You will either need to either:

- export to a Unix folder (`/tmp` or a subfolder under your login) and download the `csv` to PC via EG
- ask your Unix admin to mount the VA019 windows share in Unix and give you rights to write to it.

In either case the code running in Unix hosted SAS will have to change the `proc export outfile=` path.